# Bootstrap carousal caption position at right bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

How to position the caption at right bottom, with maximum width and responsive ?
I don't want the caption out side the image. I set the following properties.

```
    .carousel-caption {
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    background-color:black;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Once I set the  max-width: 300px;  the caption is positioned in middle(because the right portion is trimmed by max-width). If I set margin-left, I loose responsiveness.
Do I need to use media Queries ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y67Zs/

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give value to the left attribute of your caption like this :

```
.carousel-caption {
    right: 5%;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 300px;
    left: auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Y67Zs/9/